# Yii form elements default values

Tags: forms, yii

I am creating a form like this:

```
$model = new RequestForm;
$form = new CForm('application.views.site.requestForm', $model);
```

I am saving the form data into a session, so that if the user visits some other pages where there are similar forms, the inputs are already filled. `requestForm.php` looks something like this:

```
return array(

 'showErrorSummary' => false,

 'elements' => array(
  'first_name' => array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'class' => 'standard-input',
    'value' => Yii::app()->requestFormValues->first_name,
  ),
)
```

Now the problem occurs when I submit the form. Say I have modified the first name - it gets the data from the session instead of the POST data from the input. How can I verify, in `requestForm.php` or in the `requestFormValues` component if the form was submitted so I do not specify a default value ?

Kind Regards,

Marian

Comment: Not sure is this gonna solve your issue, but I think `setFlash` and `getFlash` may help you. When you post form, set variables to flash message and call when you needed. Btw, check out this for further information: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use default value only when POST is set. Otherwise, use default

```
$RequestForm = new RequestForm;
if ( isset( $_POST['RequestForm'] ) ) {
    $RequestForm->attributes = $_POST['RequestForm'];
    // validate, save or more..
}
else {
    $RequestForm->attributes = readFromSession(); //return array
}
```

is this helps you?